# How symfony client detects the installed php clients?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony binary client to override php settings and choose my php client as described in [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#selecting-a-different-php-version).

On my first laptop, Symfony binary detects my three php clients (7.1, 7.2 and 7.3)
On my second computer, Symfony binary detects only two of the three php clients (7.1, 7.2 and 7.3)

```sh
symfony local:php:list
┌─────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │                               Directory                           │ PHP CLI │ PHP FPM │   PHP CGI   │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.2.3   │ C:\Users\a.t\Documents\Developpement\Environnements\Php\php-7.2.3 │ php.exe │         │ php-cgi.exe │ PHP CGI │         │
│ 7.3.6   │ C:\Users\a.t\Documents\Developpement\Environnements\Php\php-7.3.6 │ php.exe │         │ php-cgi.exe │ PHP CGI │ *       │
└─────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

My `C:\Users\a.t\Documents\Developpement\Environnements\Php\` directory contains three directories:
[image: Directory contains three subdirectories]

I do not know why the `php-7.1.30` subdirectory is not detected by the symfony binary. Without success, I tried to refresh directories via:

```
symfony local:php:refresh
```

How symfony client detects the installed php clients?

How to specify my first directory to unable `php7.1`?

Comment: try to add path `C:\Users\a.t\Documents\Developpement\Environnements\Php\php-7.1.30` to environment variable  `PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony is looking into different variables, mostly `PATH` variables.

See:

https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/master/PhpExecutableFinder.php
https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/master/ExecutableFinder.php

You may have set different environments on both computers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had set different environments on both computers.
Thanks for the link too!